# How to set NavigationCacheMode in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I set NavigationCacheMode in construtor and recieve an error

```
Error   1   Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Controls.Page.NavigationCacheMode' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

please help me

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Phone Silverlight apps, the cache mode policy is fixed:

- Every journal entry has a unique instance of the page

Normally this means every page on the back-stack is a "live" instance. There is no way to re-use existing instances. If your app is suspended & terminated and then resumed, pages in the back-stack don't exist until you navigate back to them, but you will still get a unique instance per journal entry.

If you want to preserve your application in the back-stack even when the user presses the Back key, set the [`PauseOnBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.pauseonback(v=vs.105).aspx) property to `true`.

Comment: Facebook is an xap, not appx. How does it persist on NavigationCache, when no other apps can?

Comment: Are you assuming they are using `PhoneApplicationPage` instances?

Comment: How else can I can give my Silverlight app, the ability to stay in multitasker even if the user presses back key and exits?

Comment: That's a completely different question from the one originally asked; it has nothing to do with `NavigationCacheMode` whatsoever. I updated the answer with the information.